# Store Follows of users in a table

Tags: mysql, database

I've got the following situation: I want to store data, which represents, if a user is following another user. Another table, which I cannot touch, stores the users, where the `username` is the primary key (unfortunatly no id...).

The fact is, if one user follows another one, it doesn't mean, that the other one is following the first one.

Right now, I designed the table with two `varchar's (128)` and a `UNIQUE INDEX` on these two varchar's which represent the usernames.

The problem is, that I need to parse some old-styled system now, and I finished like **15%** and I've got **550k** entries on this table already.

The index is bigger then **16MB**, and the data just **14MB**.

What could I do, to save this data in a better way? As said, I cannot use id's instead of the usernames, because the user-table uses the username as primary key.

Comment: Extrapolated, you'll end up with 4mln rows and 200MB of data. Why would that be a problem? If you insist on minimizing the size of the table, you could use an intermediate table where you add an ID to each user and use the id of this table as the source for your FollowUser table. It would cut the size to a bit more than half but honestly, why bother?

Comment: It is bothering me, because of the bigger size of the index then the data itself :/

Comment: Perhaps you can you use both fields as primary key. MySQL uses the primary key as a clustered index. If I understand it correctly, this would remove the seperate index alltogether.

Comment: Is that possible? I am using Navicat to administrate my database and afaik, I jsut can use one PK per table, anything else are special indexes. How does that work? (Maybe as an real answer here, cause it seems like a good way and then you should get the credits for that :) )

Comment: A table can only have one primary key, you are not mistaken about that but I assumed that your table didn't have one yet. You mentioned that you *designed the table with two varchars*. I assumed that was all the table contained with no primary key but with a unique index. My suggestion was to create primary key on those both fields and remove the index.

Comment: Nono, there is no PK yet. Just an UNIQUE index to both columns. So, instead of UNIQUE I should take PRIMARY then. I will try that out tonight.

Comment: Ok, it worked! The Index size decreased and its still unique :D Write it as an answer, so I can check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, creating a seperate index on all columns essentially forces MySQL to duplicate all data in the index.

Instead of creating a seperate `unique index`, you can create a `primary key` consisting of both of your fields. MySQL uses the `primary key` as a `clustered index` making sure your uniqueness constraint is still satisfied without increasing the size of your database.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider building your own index table that contains ID > username.

You could then use the ID's to map the followers.

This will cause for some extra overhead if you want to retrieve all the data.

Comment: Possible but instead of the bigger index of the connections table, I've got a seperate table with ids and names.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in my answer ;-)